# mysql - SELECT UNTIL in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I want to select rows until I found a certain value and it's not numeric so I cannot use > or <. How can I do this ?

Example :

```
-----
Value
-----
45
434
348
213
543
3445
343
123
34345
```

I want to select all records before 543 (NOT ORDERED BY anything)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The > and < operators work on non-numeric data.

Comment: Do give an example of sample data and what you'd like to achieve on it.

Comment: A table is not an array, it has not an inherent order. So what column(s) do you want to order by?

Comment: I edited the question .. check it now

Comment: You can't select records before `543` *not ordered by anything*. As @TimSchmelter said, there is no inherent order on a table

Comment: not so much impossible as illogical. (assuming we're understanding the question correctly)

Comment: Not so much impossible as indeterminate. The result cannot be guaranteed to be always the same.

Comment: If you want both the *before* (which **implies** an order), and the *not ordered by* (which **requires** *not to be an order*), you see that the intersection of the two sets of ways in which it can be done is empty. You need to do this in a language other than SQL (and by doing this, you *will* imply an order -- the order of extraction).

Comment: Per your edit, what determines the original order of Value as you listed it, and why is it relevant to your proposed SELECT?

Comment: I meant the column value is not ordered and it should be not ordered ! and that's actually the problem that I cannot solve :)

Comment: "When the going get tough, the toughs cheat". You can order by *a different column*! :-)

Comment: If "the column value is not ordered and it should not be ordered", why is anything prior to value 543 relevant?

Answer (score 6):

This answer might be late, but since it's the first result on google with term of 'mysql select until' hope this might help someone.

What you can do is declare a marker and if you found the value needed, set the marker to any value other than `NULL`. Then we can use `ISNULL` for checking if we have reached the row.

```
SET @marker = NULL;
SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE ISNULL(@marker:=IF(value=543,value,@marker));
```

[Here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccbe58e/1)

Comment: While this may return the desired result, I suspect it will perform a full table or index scan: most likely the optimizer does not realize that the condition will never become true again once it is false, and thus continue to load every remaining row and evaluate the condition, only that exclude that row again. For large data sets, that wastes a lot of effort. (Let me know if there is an optimization I am unaware of.)

Answer (score 5):

Having cleared the problem of "not there being an order", that is, you will have to choose some kind of ordering (for example the order of primary key, or the order in which the records were assigned OIDs), your question becomes:

```
"I want all the records whose ordering field is less than the value
 of the row for which ordering field is minimum, and VALUE is 543".
```

So you select the minimum row for which the value is 543

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM yourtable WHERE value = 543
```

or maybe, for other purposes, something like

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM yourtable WHERE value >= 543
```

and then select all records before that one:

```
SELECT value FROM yourtable WHERE id < ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM yourtable WHERE value = 543 );
```

So your table could be:

```
ID    Value
-----------
1     45
2     434
3     348
4     213
5     543
6     3445
7     343
8     123
9     34345
```

and you  would get:

```
45
434
348
213
543
```

You don't see the order, but there *must* be one. Here it is the order on `id`.

As you requested, `value` can be whatever - a text, or even an image BLOB - and the "ordering" stays hidden.

In some other language you would do something like:

```
qry = SQL.exec('SELECT * FROM yourtable;');
while ((value = qry.next().value) != '543':
    write value '\n'
qry.close()
```

but then either the `SELECT`'s order would not be specified, and you might get every time a different result, or it would be the order of tuple insertion in the table. Which is the same as using `id` explicitly.

Comment: @Fady What do you want to happen if 543 appears more than once in your values?

Answer (score -5):

You can just use an equality comparator in the query, to directly search the value you're looking for.

Why would you want to loop through your database until you found it when you can just specify what you're searching for ?

You didn't give an example of what value it is you're searching for, so if it is a string

```
Select x.* from table x WHERE x.Column = 'String Value'
```

However, if you do want to put some extra load on your database (which it is in this undefined case), you'd have a stored procedure, looping through ID's stored in the database.

For that, take a look at the following post, which might give you some inspiration : [SQL LOOP INSERT Based on List of ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555841/sql-loop-insert-based-on-list-of-ids)

Comment: This doesn't really answer what was asked.