# order by date and select until specific id is reached

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with `ID, STATUS, DATE` columns, the rows in the table are ordered by DATE, I want to get all the rows until a specific ID is reached, and then stop, something like:

```
SELECT FROM myTable WHERE `DATE` <= '2017-10-09' ORDER BY `DATE` ASC UNTIL? `ID` = 119;
```

[image]

I like to know if that is possible somehow, to stop on a specific ID, whatever the ID was..

Thanks.

**EDIT EXPLAINING**

I want to select rows that are ordered under any column, but stop when a specific provided ID is reached. in the above image the result should be all the rows except the ones below the row 119.

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Why don't you just change `<=` to `<` and ignore everything on that date you don't want?

Comment: This wont work if you check the image I recently attached.

Comment: I got this idea by checking the image. You want it to stop before 9th october is reached, so just don't select records from that date.

Comment: No no, it was a random chosen ID, i want to stop on a specific ID, whatever the ID was.

Comment: `ordered under any column` ... this requirement isn't specific enough to write an exact query.  You need to tell us _which_ column is being used to order.

Comment: In this example exactly it is the Date, that is enough to solve my problem, I was just wondering if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029807/522479) might work:

```
SET @marker = NULL;
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE `DATE` <= '2017-10-09'
    AND ISNULL(@marker := IF(id = 119, 1, @marker))
ORDER BY `DATE` ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as expected, I am trying to make it work as a Laravel DB Query, do you think it would work?

Answer (score 1):

You should phrase the query to select records whose date is less than the date of the record for which `ID = 119`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE DATE <= (SELECT DATE FROM myTable WHERE ID = 119);
```

Comment: Sorry i changed the ID in the question to avoid the misunderstanding, Im testing your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it return the same exact result.

Comment: Edit your question and show us clear input and the expected output.  _Delete_ the illegible screen capture, and _do not_ include images.

Comment: Thanks, I did my best, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Biegeleisen's answer is correct, but if you have no time in your date field then the order by is going to use the date and then any ordered indexes you have specified. So you will get all of the records back that equal the date of the id specified in the subquery's WHERE clause.

So for example, you are going to also return the rows for ids 200-202, no way around that unless you provide more precision on your date OR add the id field to your order by clause, in which case you'll need to be comfortable excluding all IDs above the specified ids integer value for the same date.