# MySQL count ordered

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I'm using the MySQL "search until" feature, and having in mind the example on https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029807/5807146, I am getting the correctly ordered results:

```
SELECT * FROM table, (SELECT @until_var := NULL) _until
WHERE ISNULL(@until_var := IF(value = 100, value, @until_var))
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Next what I need (and have no success by) is to count ordered:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table, (SELECT @until_var := NULL) _until
WHERE ISNULL(@until_var := IF(value = 100, value, @until_var))
ORDER BY value DESC
```

It always returns the count of founds, without respect to the `ORDER BY`.

Example: In a DB where column `id` is the primary index, and column `date` could be anything, I am trying to make MySQL count from the entries with highest date:

```
 id | value | date
----|-------|----------
 1  | A     | mar
 2  | A     | jan
 3  | A     | apr
 4  | B     | feb

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table, (SELECT @until_var := NULL) _until
WHERE value = "A" AND ISNULL(@until_var := IF(id = 4, value, @until_var))
ORDER BY date DESC
```

With desired results:

```
 id | value | date
----|-------|----------
 3  | A     | apr
 1  | A     | mar

= 2
```

My current (slow) solution would be to get column `id`, and then count the results ... but this is slow. The goal is to be as fast as possible.

Comment: I don't follow your question.  What does `value` have to do with the count?  You have a `select count(*)` and then the desired results have multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand, what you want. But from your example I think

```
SELECT e.id,
       e.value,
       e.date
       FROM elbat e
            INNER JOIN (SELECT value,
                               max(date) date
                               FROM elbat
                               GROUP BY value) gd
                       ON gd.value = e.value
                          AND gd.date = e.date;
```

might be what you're searching for? (You'd have to use a proper type for `date` though, as the strings of the months' name won't be sorted after the number of the corresponding months. Or use a mapping table mapping the values to integers defining the order.)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, then I'd suggest as by your example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table, (SELECT @until_var := NULL) _until
WHERE value = "A"
HAVING ISNULL(@until_var := IF(id = 4, value, @until_var))
ORDER BY date DESC
```

It first gets all results, then sorts them, and thereafter gets (counts) everything till the target id is reached. It is indeed slower than without a `HAVING` clause, but it works.