# Select between range in sql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I need a suggestion, while select only rows when a certain range met. For example, here is below dataset;

```
id|count|name|status
_________________

1| 10 | xxx | 0

2| 20 | yyy | 0

3| 30 | zzz | 1

4| 40 | qqq | 0

5| 50 | ppp | 0
```

I want to select only between 0 and 1 expected result;

```
id|count|name|status
_________________

1| 10 | xxx | 0

2| 20 | yyy | 0

3| 30 | zzz | 1
```

SQL : `select * from test_db.table where status between 0 and 1`

But I got entire data when executing the above query

But I got entire values from that table. Please give me any suggestions, I'm stuck on this.

Comment: I don't know hadoop, if you want this query in Sqlserver, then I will make it. do you want?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah i want only sql query

Comment: Please explain why in your opinion rows with id=4 and id=5 should not be returned in the result of your query. They have status=0, it is between 0 and 1.

Comment: @leftjoin i want only batch of data only between 0 to 1 thats why. Thats is completed or processed dataset, others still processing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test_db.table WHERE id <= ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM test_db.table WHERE status = '1' );
```

I had a similar situation some moths ago, I adapted LSerni's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019482/mysql-select-until-in-sql).

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
SELECT * from sample_table WHERE status>0 AND status<1;
```

Comment: Hey @T.Maharani I already tried this no i didn't get exact as expected result

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows between the 1st status = 0 and the 1st status = 1:

```
select * from test_db.table 
where id between
  (select min(id) from test_db.table where status = 0)
  and 
  (select min(id) from test_db.table where status = 1)
```